# Yii2 and Materialize CSS

Tags: php, yii2, materialize, yii2-advanced-app

I have combed throught the internet and this site, but, I cannot find the answer to my question. I have installed Materializecss via composer as mentioned on this site:
https://github.com/MacGyer/yii2-materializecss

I have the macgyer folder in the /vendor directory. I am using the Advanced template.

I then created an asset file called MaterializeAsset.php with the following code and in the directory /frontend/assets/

```
namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main frontend application asset bundle.
 */
class MaterializeAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'macgyer/yii2materializecss/assets/MaterializeAsset',
    ];
}
```

I then modified the asset registration code in the main.php, located in the directory: \frontend\views\layouts\main.php, as follows:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
//use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
use frontend\assets\MaterializeAsset;
use common\widgets\Alert;

//AppAsset::register($this);
MaterializeAsset::register($this);
```

Now when I load my site, I get the error:
    ReflectionException
    Class macgyer/yii2materializecss/assets/MaterializeAsset does not exits

I am really not sure what is going on, any help will be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using incorrect class name for `$depends` - it should contain `\` instead of `/`:

```
public $depends = [
    'macgyer\yii2materializecss\assets\MaterializeAsset',
];
```

or

```
public $depends = [
    \macgyer\yii2materializecss\assets\MaterializeAsset::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, to answer my own question. Modify the composer.json file with :

```
"require": {
    "macgyer/yii2-materializecss": "~3.0.0"
},
```

Then run the following command in the command prompt

```
composer update
```

Once that is done, reload the web app, and it all works fine.